# angular: apply css class if val > val

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set css class based on condition from val1 and val2 values.
`if val2 > val1` set css class `has-error`

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': {{obj.amount2 > obj.amount1}}}">
```

```
val 1: {{obj.amount1}}
```

```
val 2: {{obj.amount2}}
```

```
{{obj.amount2 > obj.amount1}}
```

- val 1: 100
- val 2: 200

this always returns false

Comment: Is it AngularJS or Angular 2+?

Comment: ng-class="{'has-error':  obj.amount2 > obj.amount1 }"

Comment: Given the syntax, I'd say AJS, so I'll edit the tags. If it's Angular, please use the correct syntax and edit the tags back. Either way, provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib AngularJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use binding to evaluate the object.

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': obj.amount2 > obj.amount1}">
```

OR

```html
<div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="obj.amount2 > obj.amount1">
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
<div ng-if="val 2>val 1">
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': val 2 > val 1}">
</div>
```